# nsfdbopen returns 535 status

Tags: c++, lotus, lotus-notes

I am using the Notes API to do some work and I am running in to the following issue. NSFDbOpen keeps returning a status of 535. I am unable to figure out what that status code means, OSLoadString has not worked for me. Does any one know what this status code means?

Comment: I'm assuming that 535 is a decimal, so convert that to hex value 0x0217. We need the hex for the prefix byte, and note that in globerr.h the value 0x0200 corresponds to PKG_NSF, so that makes sense. The second byte is 17, but we need that back in decimal, to match it up to an offset in nsferr.h. That's 23 in decimal, but it leads to a dead end in nsferr.h, because the value PKG_NSF+23 doesn't resolve to an error message. It resolves to the identifier DBD_NOCACHE_STRING, with value "NoCache". That doesn't make much sense for a return from NSFDbOpen.

Comment: Note: I'm looking at the files in the Noets API Toolkit version 7, which is not the latest. And I don't know what toolkit you are using.  You should check in your version of nsferr.h to see if PKG_NSF+23 has a more sensible definition. If it does, that's your first clue. If it doesn't, then post your code, and tell us a bit more about what's you've done to valdiate that the arguments are right, that you have access to the server and to the database that you're trying to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a smart man. My problem was that I had not yet called NotesInit(). Once I did things started to run much better.